# How do I turn off 1-line error reporting in Failsafe?

Tags: maven, maven-failsafe-plugin

I dislike this feature: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/newerrorsummary.html  Is there a way to turn it off so it reports full stack traces and errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the surefire/failsafe `configuration` element:

```
<trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
```