# How to get the 1 line error summary in maven output?

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

I want the opposite of this question: [How do I turn off 1-line error reporting in Failsafe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927267/how-do-i-turn-off-1-line-error-reporting-in-failsafe), so i did the opposite as it's explained there, i put `<trimStackTrace>true</trimStackTrace>` to the `<configuration>` section of the "maven-surefire-plugin" but I still didn't get the "1-line error summary" as described here: [The 1-line error summary](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/newerrorsummary.html), I'm getting this output when I type:

`mvn clean test`

or generating the html report with:

`mvn surefire-report:report site -DgenerateReports=false -Dtest=TestWebPcQubitArV5`

With both commands i get this level of verbosity for every failed test case:

```
Running tv.qubit.suites.TestWebPcQubitCoV5
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 196.798 sec <<< FAILURE! - in tv.qubit.suites.TestWebPcQubitCoV5
testLandingPage(tv.qubit.suites.TestWebPcQubitCoV5)  Time elapsed: 40.344 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: 
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Comenzá tu mes gratis"}
  (Session info: chrome=53.0.2785.92)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.23.409687 (c46e862757edc04c06b1bd88724d15a5807b84d1),platform=Linux 4.7.2-1-ARCH x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 30.06 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '31c43c8', time: '2016-08-02 21:57:56 -0700'
System info: host: 'arch', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.7.2-1-ARCH', java.version: '1.8.0_102'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.23.409687 (c46e862757edc04c06b1bd88724d15a5807b84d1), userDataDir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.m22jAs}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=53.0.2785.92, platform=LINUX, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 036114974517a8f9c7215f2e615ffb27
*** Element info: {Using=link text, value=Comenzá tu mes gratis}
    at tv.qubit.suites.TestWebPcQubitCoV5.testLandingPage(TestWebPcQubitCoV5.java:67)
```

When I suppose I get something like the documentation says:

```
Failed tests:
  Test1.assertion1:59 Bending maths expected:<[123]> but was:<[312]>
  Test1.assertion2:64 True is false

Tests in error:
  Test1.nullPointerInLibrary:38 » NullPointer
  Test1.failInMethod:43->innerFailure:68 NullPointer Fail here
  Test1.failInLibInMethod:48 » NullPointer
  Test1.failInNestedLibInMethod:54->nestedLibFailure:72 » NullPointer
  Test2.test6281:33 Runtime FailHere
```

Comment: The above output `For documentaition...` is from seleinum...and from Maven..

Comment: Yes, both outputs are, the first one is the output from maven i get but is also a selenium output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad... The 1 line output is showed below the full trace of each error. As I'm a begginer with maven, I wrongly thinked that the output will show ONLY the 1 line brief error, instead of everything...

Here's the below part of the maven full output:

```
Results :

Tests in error: 
tv.qubit.suites.TestWebPcQubitCoV5.testLandingPage(tv.qubit.suites.TestWebPcQubitCoV5)
  Run 1: TestWebPcQubitCoV5.testLandingPage:67 » NoSuchElement no such element: Unable ...
  Run 2: TestWebPcQubitCoV5.testLandingPage:67 » NoSuchElement no such element: Unable ...
  Run 3: TestWebPcQubitCoV5.testLandingPage:67 » NoSuchElement no such element: Unable ...
```